# How to force to rotate the screen of iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, jailbreak, tweak

I'm writing a tweak for jailbroken iOS device, which is closely related to the device orientation, it should **force** the whole screen to a specified orientation and **keep** it at that orientation. This tweak is running inside `SpringBoard` and `Backboardd`, I tried the code below, but doesn't work. does anyone know that?

```
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:orientation];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

Comment: maybe you can use this code,
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];

Answer (score -1):

**Call the same code(which I written below) in `viewDidAppear:` method.**

Objective C:-

```
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:orientation];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

Swift:-

```
let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.orientation.rawValue
UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```

Comment: The code is running inside SpringBoard and BackBoardd, so no viewDidApear usable.